# Convert pdf file to thumbnail set from http:// url in imageview without download pdf

Tags: java, android, pdf, android-bitmap

I want to set thumbnail of pdf page from http:// Url in Imageview in android.Please let me know guys. Or if i get bitmap of pdf or create bitmap so i can set pdf thumbnail in imageview.

Comment: Ask the maintainers of the Web server that has the PDF if they publish thumbnail images of the PDF. Otherwise, you will need to download the PDF (or at least part of it) to generate a thumbnail.

Comment: they are not provide thumbnail images from server they give only pdf link.

Comment: any answers yet? I too want to add this. Only the thing is that my pdf files are stored on the firebase storage